# Importing multiple CSV files

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, worksheet-function

I have to run a daily stock analysis where I pull multiple .csv files, and then have to go through an annoying task of deleting unnecessary fields from the .csv's. Only then can I start compiling the data into one sheet.

I then have to copy and paste part of a .csv from a server login. I cannot import the .csv file from the server.

I then have to sift through huge data from two different sources to eventually get to a point where I can begin compiling a report to have stock replenished in the correct areas.

I have been using the conditional formatting tool, which does make it easier to identify the data, but it still takes me +- 2 hours ( if I work very quickly ) to do this.

What I need help with is to:

- 1) Import only the data I need from the selected .csv files.
- 2) When I paste the data from the server how do I get the rows that have the same product information to line up next to each other i.e: My stock on hand list is on the left and my stock availability list from the paste lines up on the right(after I have done the paste).

Naturally doing this every day gets very grueling and I need a solution to simplify this process.

Comment: Please provide some example sheets so we have an idea of the data you're trying to work with. I'm not sure if Excel has built-in user-friendly features that can help with this, but it might be something that can be done with VBA or PowerShell.

Comment: If you can not import from the server, can you copy the `.csv` files to your computer so you can do the import properly?

Comment: If you provide test files, it will be a lot easier to help. You have several steps here you want to automate, so our general advice will not be as useful.

Comment: This sounds more like something to be done using data bases as @Sun writes or even R. In R you can read csv files, drop columns and rows that you don't want, and merge files, to line up the things you need. Then export from R. There is an Excel plugin that calls R, but this sounds like you will need to program.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to give a specific answer with what you said but Power Query ( free add in from Microsoft) is designed to automate this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have PowerQuery (only available more expensive versions of Office Excel 2013), you might consider utilizing Microsoft Access and just use  Excel as the product that refreshes/views the data.

Access is better suited for what you want to do.

As long as you download the CSV to the same location and it has the same file name, you can link to it as a table in Microsoft Access. During the link process, you can ignore certain fields during the link. Once all the CSVs are linked, you will need to create a query to normalize all the different CSVs.

For example, you have one CSV that has two fields: productid and soh (stock on hand). Your other CSV has two fields: productid and sa (stock availability).

Microsoft Access can then be used to create a query where you can display one line for productid and have two columns for soh and sa. Then you can do further calculations on how much to order if you have other fields like minimum order quantity or safety stock... to arrive at a number that you need to order based on your requirements.

In Excel, you just use the Data Refresh feature to update the list.

Feel free to contact me and I'd be happy to walk you through the process. If you have TeamViewer, we can do a remote session.